# How to write a more efficient macro for returning the highest value in column A

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that loops through all the values in column A and returns the highest value plus one to the selected cell.

I've been trying to think up a more efficient way to do the same task, and have no good solution. I tried using `WorksheetFunction.Max` but it requires every single cell being compared as an input (there are several thousand cells in column A.)

I thought about sorting column A by values highest to lowest, but I would like to preserve the current order.

Any ideas? I need the macro to return **a value** and not a formula.

Thanks

Comment: @SiddharthRout Unreal. I swear I put that exact line into VBA and received an error, but now it is working 100%. Maybe I left out the quotes like a fool. THanks.

Comment: No worries.) I have shown you two examples in the answer below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to pass individual cells to `Application.WorksheetFunction.Max` if you want to find the maximum value in Col A. Simply pass the entire column. For example

```
Debug.Print Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Columns("A:A"))
```

And if you want to pass a specific range then use this

```
Debug.Print Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("A1:A50"))
```

The above is an example. Do not forget to fully qualify your range. For example

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A50"))
```

**Edit**

Another way. This finds the last cell which has data in Col A and then constructs the range.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lrow As Long
    Dim rng As Range

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        lrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        Set rng = .Range("A1:A" & lrow)

        Debug.Print Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(rng)
    End With
End Sub
```